# Directory of the file to be opened

Tags: c, file

```
int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("pr1.c","r");
    if(fp==NULL)
    {
        printf("can not open file");
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

In the above code, the file `pr1.c` should be in the same directory in which I am working, othwerwise it will print `can not open file`.
Is there any way by which I can open a file which is present anywhere in my computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. Just use the full path of the file, or relative path based on current folder.

For example:

```
fp = fopen("c:\\MyDirectory\\TestFile1.txt", "r");
fp = fopen("/full/path/to/TestFile1.txt", "r");   // use ../ go to parent folder
```

---

**Updated:** If you want user to enter the path, you can use

```
char path[201];
scanf("%200s",path);    // read from user
fp = fopen(path, "r");
```

Comment: is it possible to make it in such a way that the user enter the full path

Comment: is it necessary to mention the extension of the file

Comment: @zee Yes, it must contains the extension.

Answer (score 1):

Yes use the full path

eg.

```
 fp = fopen("/etc/passwd", "r");
```

Or you can use relative paths!